# Adding a new sheet to a Google Spreadsheet via the Google Docs or Spreadsheet API

Tags: google-docs, google-sheets, google-docs-api, google-sheets-api

I'm working on a project where I'm pulling a bunch of information out of a Drupal MySQL database and putting it in a Google Spreadsheet. My problem is that its a lot of data, and I'd prefer to put it all in one spreadsheet, sorting everything by sheet.

I'm not seeing anyway to add a sheet to a spreadsheet nor navigate between existing sheets.  Anyone have any idea how to do this?  I'd like to this in PHP, and if that doesn't work, Python.

Thanks for your help,

--Scott

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help
http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/3.0/developers_guide.html#CreatingWorksheets

It's for Protocol/Java though.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheet#insertSheet

I guess, you first stumbled along a very similar URL:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_spreadsheetapp#create